# TensorflowJS predict asynchronously

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, async-await, tensorflowjs-converter

I have been trying to figure out how to perform predictions using tensorflowJS in an asynchronous fashion. All my attempts resulted in the predict function blocking my code.

Looking at the [docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#model), I see that most of the functions are defined as async functions and return a promise like for example `tf.loadLayersModel`, which also works for me asynchronously without any blocking.

However, [predict](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.LayersModel.predict) doesn't return a promise but directly a `tf.Tensor`. I tried wrapping the predictions in a customly defined async function like:

```javascript
compute = async(data) => {
  var tensor = tf.tensor(data, [1, 100])
  var prediction = this.model.predict(tensor)
  return prediction.data()
}
```

But still predict is blocking the execution of my code.

What is the right approach to use TensorflowJS for asynchronous inference?

Comment: what about setTimeout?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I think running in a WebWorker is the right solution, but it isn't supported yet: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/102

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot wrap a blocking operation in a promise because that's not just how it works. See this made up example (which is basically what you're doing):

```
const blockFunction = () => {
  const endBlock = Date.now() + 2000
  while(Date.now() < endBlock){}
}

const promisedBlocking = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
  const endBlock = Date.now() + 2000

  while (Date.now() < endBlock) {}
  return res('I cannot resolve before the blocking IO')
})

console.log('before blocking')
blockFunction()
console.log('after blocking')


console.log('before promised blocking')
promisedBlocking()
.then(console.log)
console.log('after promised blocking')
```

If you're using tensorflow with node you can wrap your function calls in a separate file and call it with a child process (see the [fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) method), or if you're using TF in the browser execute the background function using [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Answer (score 0):

Warrpe your code like this (Promise based):

```
const compute = (data) => {

    try {
        const tensor = tf.tensor(data, [1, 100])
        const prediction = this.model.predict(tensor)
        return Promise.resolve(prediction.data())
    }
    catch(err){

        return Promise.reject(err)

    }

  }
```

Later :

```
compute.then(res => consonle.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```